# install shield basic msi . How to display an error dialog when the entered configuration file path is valid

Tags: installation, installshield, basic-msi

I used CheckTargetPath = 0 to validate the entered path in the textbox events. It doesn't let past to the next dialog if the path entered is not valid. But I want to display either an error message in another textbox in the same dialog or in another dialog box. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Make a clone of the SetupError Dialog, and make it look nice.

on the behavior section of your button "Next":

- add the condition `CheckTargetPath=0` to the NewDialog actions
- add a SpawnDialog (your New dialog) with a condition `CheckTargetPath<>0`

That way the user will be trapped on that dialog until you action return 0.

Don't forget to cover the unattended mode.